# facet ordering and then labeling x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have this dataframe and I'd like to use scale_x_discrete to label the x axis

```
dat = data.frame(group= c("A","B","B"),y = c(1,2,3),row = c(1,1,2),LABEL = c("la","la","lb"))

ggplot(dat, aes(x= row, y = y))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~group)+
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = row,
    labels = LABEL
  )

but I get an error:  Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'LABEL' not found
```

any idea how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `x` to be discrete, you'll need to make it a factor with `x = factor(row)`.
Then just reference the `dat` data frame explicitly in `scale_x_discrete`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(row), y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~group) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = dat$row, labels = dat$LABEL)
```

[image]

Alternately, you can keep `x` as continuous and use `scale_x_continuous` instead to relabel the ticks:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = row, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~group) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = dat$row, labels = dat$LABEL)
```